# Did the three eyed raven know this? (S6E05)

Tags: game-of-thrones

Did the three eyed raven know

> the truth about Hodor?

It seems to me that he is in control about what time and place is visited in the visions and that he always shows Bran events that are important. This means he knew what was going to happen and possibly also why it happened? Does this also mean

> He knew he (and Hodor) were going to die that very moment?

And doesn't it also mean that

> Every event is set in stone and that he actually knows both past and future events

Comment: If he knew he and Hodor were going to die, would he not have taken steps to avoid it?

Comment: Well maybe he believes in faith or something and that it's meant to be like that. Why else show that vision in the first place? If Bran saw Hodor's seizure but without the reason for it, that vision had no point

Comment: Not sure I follow your logic there. There would be no point in Bran going back in a vision at all if his objective would be for Bran to warg into Hodor.

Comment: @TLP that's why I think that eventually everything in the world is set in stone. The vision was necessary to make Hodor like that. If the raven knew it wasn't going to happen I see no point in why the raven showed him that vision

Comment: @TLP As the three eyed raven said: "The past is written, the ink is dry." He might have know it would happen, but not exactly when. Most people also seem to think that the reason Bran was in that vision and wouldn't get out of his warg state is because the 3ER was still "uploading" his knowledge into Bran.

Comment: He saw 14,000,605 scenarios and this was the only way Bran could survive

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Three-Eyed Raven is unaware that Bran can alter the past (or chooses to make him believe he can't). It would certainly appear that the Three-Eyed Raven did not have this power himself.

> You cannot speak to him, try as you might. I know. I have my own ghosts, Bran. A brother that I loved, a brother that I hated, a woman I desired. Through the trees, **I see them still, but no word of mine has ever reached them.The past remains the past. We can learn from it, but we cannot change it.** - *A Dance of Dragons, Bran 3*

However, we see in the below scene the Three-Eyed Raven knew right away that Night's King was able to interact with Bran, left his mark, and would be able  to enter the cave.

So whether events are truly set in stone or can changed is still yet to be seen... [Time travel always gets sticky like this...](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimeTravel) <<< WARNING TV TROPES LINK.

Comment: Well the show implies otherwise, because the vision certainly changed Hodor. Also the show is very different with regard of visions because in the book seeing the past is linked to places where weirwood trees are and in the show it seems to be possible anywhere

Comment: I am saying the Three-Eyed Raven could not do it. Bran may have a new/greater power.

Comment: wait... did i even answer the right question?

Comment: sorry I think I read the answer wrong. You certainly make a point, but I guess the whole time travel paradox thing complicates everything alot

Comment: @IvoBeckers no, i didnt fully answer the question. It should be better niw

Comment: I think we're led to assume that the Night's King touches Bran in a vision of the _present_, not the past. Note that the Night's King is mustering a horde of undead in Bran's vision, and soon after he arrives at the Three-Eyed Raven's cave with a horde of similar size. The Raven may be well aware that visions of the present can be interacted with (at least when those as powerful at the Night's King are involved).

Comment: @recognizer Good point, it does show that interaction is possible in a greendream in the present, and then we see it is possible in the past...